# Where to put the "new button" in a metro style app

Tags: gui-design, layout, metro, windows-8

I am creating a Windows 8 style app, and I am confused where to put the new button. I have many options I can choose from.

- **First** above the search list:

  [image]
- **Second** under the search list:

  [image]
- **Third** with window title:

  [image]
- **Fourth** inside the app bar:

  [image]

Which is better and why ?

Comment: This depends on the app...
What is the app for?
What are the user's goals while using it?
Is the "new" functionality a frequently used operation?

Comment: good question "Is the "new" functionality a frequently used operation?" no not frequently

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's usually a better idea to show the "add new" option in the same grid/list that displays the existing collection of items (especially for admin management pages).

How about the following 2 options?

This one displays the add icon to the far right corner of the page.

[image]

This one displays it right next to the title; a bit more convenient.

[image]

Comment: i liked the second one more, thanks. what if i create a pop up menu has new,comments,... opened when a user click on products?

Answer (score 10):

Note that *especially* if your page is only displaying one type of item in the list (and its the only list), the Windows 8 guidelines say you should actually be placing your new button in the app bar, on the right-hand side.

You can check out the relevant UX guidelines from Microsoft here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761499.aspx